# Can I shorten PersonViewModel to PersonModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC theory, the Model is the business domain class. For instance, we can have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In ASP.NET MVC, a ViewModel class is often used. This class can be tailored to suit a specific View:

```
public class PersonViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deactivate { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, `FirstName` and `LastName` will be combined in one string (`Name`), and there will also be a "Deactivate" checkbox on the form which will cause deactivation of the person.

In Controller, we populate the `PersonViewModel` object from the `Person` object. But, on the very first line of the View, we declare that the **Model** for this View is `PersonViewModel`.

```
@model PersonViewModel
```

Isn't the Model actually the class that is bound to the View (at least as far as ASP.NET MVC is concerned)?

If my Model is actually the `PersonViewModel` class, can I call this class just `PersonModel`? Or is this wrong and misleading?

In my opinion, this is easier to write (and read), and it would also be easier to explain to developers just starting with ASP.NET MVC. Isn't it better to leave out the ViewModel term completely, which can be confused with the ViewModel in the MVVM pattern?

Comment: When you use "PersonViewModel" this is 100% sure you are using this model for a View, while PersonModel can be missleading

Comment: I would argue that `PersonViewModel` is clearer in defining the intent than `PersonModel` (which could be confused with a data/domain model). The most important thing is to be consistent.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I agree that "PersonViewModel" is the better approach after all. If you would repost your comment as answer, I would mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ZivWeissman - If you would also like to repost your comment as answer, I would upvote it or mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is no absolute answer to this question,
What the convention "says" is that "PersonViewModel" is a class that is based on "Person" class, but is to be used in an MVC View.
Even in the basic MVC projects you have LoginViewModel etc... so it is also should be understandable for new mvc developers.

For just using PersonModel, is confusing because "Person" is already a Model, so why naming a class PersonModel? doesn't make sense. 
If you want to shorten it, you should use PersonView. (but again, the convention is PersonViewModel)

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no good answer for this question. Both of the names you provided are self explanatory and could be used.

As Robert C. Martin writes in his books in such situation the most important thing is consistency and standardization. If you work in team of few developers you should use common approach to such problem and always use same code pattern to avoid confusion. Because such confusion is a waste of developers time.

I would recommend you this [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) brilliant book about clean code where you can find answers and suggestions for many problems like this one.

---

In my current team we would use such convention:

`PersonDom` - person data object model
`Person` - person view model